# Collect lists to joint list using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to write an expression that takes data from caches (they return a List)  and collect everything together.

I came up with:

```
List<myDto> myJointSnapshot = cachesMap.values().stream()
  .flatMap(c->c.getSnapshot()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where getSnapshot returns also List< myDto>.

This gives me an error: *no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that List< myDto> conforms to Stream< ? extends R>*

How I can correct the expression to be valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
flatMap(c->c.getSnapshot().stream())...
```

`flatMap` is expecting a `Stream` as a result, in your case it is a `List`.

Answer (score 3):

To better understand you can split in 2 steps

```
// Lambda
List<myDto> myJointSnapshot = cachesMap.values().stream()
                                                .map(c -> c.getSnapShot())
                                                .flatMap(l->l.stream())
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Method reference
List<myDto> myJointSnapshot = cachesMap.values().stream()
                                                .map(Caches::getSnapshot) // replace 'Caches' by real type
                                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```